# Weighted probability, is my formula correct?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, notation

For a programming project I'm using a function to calculate a score based on a set of questions a student has answered. The questions are weighted so that more recent questions are worth more.

I have it working in my code, and I need to make sure my Maths formula is correct for documentation. Is this right?

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{ic}{\sum_{i=1}^n i}$$

where c = answer (correct = 1, incorrect = 0). (do I just write this line below the formula?)

So, example:

| i (question number (earliest to latest)) | c (correct = 1; incorrect = 0) | ic | (ic)/sum(i) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 0.066 |
| 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 | 0.2 |
| 4 | 1 | 4 | 0.266 |
| 5 | 1 | 5 | 0.333 |
|  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  | **0.866** |

Score: 0.866

Comment: Your formula can  also be written as $\frac{2}{n(n+1)}\sum_{i=1}^n ic_i$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- $c$ is not a constant, rather it depends on $i$. We introduce the notation $c_i$ as an indicator if the $i$-th question is answered correctly.
- You have used the index $i$ twice for different purposes. Note that we have $\sum_{i=1}^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$.

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{ic_i}{\sum_{j=1}^n j}=\frac{2}{n(n+1)}\sum_{i=1}^n ic_i$$

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have intended the formula to be $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n ic}{\sum_{i=1}^n i}$ (in fact it looks like this expression is what you calculated in your table, so you might have just made a latexing error), as that personally seems more reasonable to me.

In general, if the $i^\text{th}$ question has relative weight $a_i$ (in your case $a_i=i$), then the formula should look like $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n a_ic_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i}$, where $c_i$ is the score on the $i^\text{th}$ question (in your case $c_i\in\{0,1\}$ whether they missed it or not).